# Tensorflow: InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I get the above error for the following code that is supposed to find a conic section that best fits the source image:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2

# import image
img = cv2.imread('stinkbug.png')
height, width, channels = img.shape

# blur image
img = cv2.blur(img, (5, 5))

# posterize image
n = 4    # Number of levels of quantization
indices = np.arange(0,256)   # List of all colors
divider = np.linspace(0,255,n+1)[1] # we get a divider
quantiz = np.int0(np.linspace(0,255,n)) # we get quantization colors
color_levels = np.clip(np.int0(indices/divider),0,n-1) # color levels 0,1,2..
palette = quantiz[color_levels] # Creating the palette
im2 = palette[img]  # Applying palette on image
im2 = cv2.convertScaleAbs(im2) # Converting image back to uint8
img = im2

# create graph image
graph = np.zeros((height, width, 3), np.uint8)
graph[:] = (255, 255, 255)
cv2.imwrite('grf.png', graph)

# Model parameters
A = tf.Variable([20], tf.int32)
B = tf.Variable([20], tf.int32)
C = tf.Variable([20], tf.int32)
D = tf.Variable([20], tf.int32)
E = tf.Variable([20], tf.int32)
F = tf.Variable([20], tf.int32)
G = tf.Variable([20], tf.int32)
Red = tf.Variable([20], tf.int32)
Green = tf.Variable([20], tf.int32)
Blue = tf.Variable([20], tf.int32)

#inputs
pic = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(height, width))
out = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(height, width))

sess = tf.Session()

# model
def conic_model(x, y):
    tf.multiply(A, (x+F)) ** 2 + tf.multiply(tf.multiply(B, (x+F)), (y+G)) + tf.multiply(C, (y+G)) ** 2 + tf.multiply(D, (x+F)) + tf.multiply(E, (y+G))
def f1(): return (Red, Green, Blue)
def f2(): return (255, 255, 255)
decider = tf.cond(tf.less(conic_model(out.eval(session=sess), out[0].eval(session=sess)), 0), f1(), f2())
grf = decider

# loss
combo = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(pic - grf))
loss = combo / (height * width)

# optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

# training loop
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
for i in range(1000):
  sess.run(train, feed_dict={pic:img, out:graph})
```

The error occurs on line 42, out = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(height, width)). Out is supposed to be just (255, 255, 255), so I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: You dont have line numbers, so line 42 is something I doubt people are going to count.  Perhaps you could edit your code sample to point out the line with the error.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see right now is that your input is not really correct. Your placeholders are:

```
pic = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(height, width))
out = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(height, width))
```

While your images are of shape (height,width,3) <- color channels

Can you try fixing this and see if this works?